# realtime update using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Main question:- i want to change div - test1 as we change select value in realtime

below six line are to increase the explanation lol

I want data[0][3] to change as we change data[0][2] in test1 div

I have tried manually updated basis array calculation still no luck

further i might also need to use in calculating data[1][3]

I want data[0][3] to change as we change data[0][2] in test1 div

I have tried manually updated basis array calculation still no luck

further i might also need to use in calculating data[1][3]

```js
  var data = [
            ["DEC", 555, 15,],
            ["JAN", 505, 15,],
            ["FEB", 575, 15,],
            ["MAR", 565, 15,],
        ];
        function getOption() {
            selectElement = document.querySelector('#select1');
            output = selectElement.value;
            data[0][2] = output;
        }
        var test1 = $("#test1");
        var div = $("<div>", { text: data[0][1] / data[0][2], class: "div-added" });
        test1.append(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div>
                <script>
                    document.write(data[0][0])
                </script>
            </div>
            <div id="test1">
            </div>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control" id="Select1" onselect="getOption()">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                    <option>13</option>
                    <option>14</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>16</option>
                    <option>17</option>
                    <option>18</option>
                    <option>19</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please clarify your question properly

Comment: i want to change div - test1 as we change select value in realtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer below code. You have used wrong variable names  while accessing in javascript code and its logic.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var data = [
            ["DEC", 555, 15,],
            ["JAN", 505, 15,],
            ["FEB", 575, 15,],
            ["MAR", 565, 15,],
        ];
        function getOption() {
            selectElement = document.getElementById("Select1");
            output = selectElement.value;
            data[0][2] = output;

        var test1 = $('.card-body').children('div#test1');
        var div = $("<div>", { text: data[0][1] / data[0][2], class: "div-added" });
        test1.append(div);
        }
   </script>
<div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div>
                <script>
                    document.write(data[0][0])
                </script>
            </div>
            <div id="test1">
            </div>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control" id="Select1" onchange="getOption()">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                    <option>8</option>
                    <option>9</option>
                    <option>10</option>
                    <option>11</option>
                    <option>12</option>
                    <option>13</option>
                    <option>14</option>
                    <option>15</option>
                    <option>16</option>
                    <option>17</option>
                    <option>18</option>
                    <option>19</option>
                    <option>20</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, you can access functionality. Try to implement logic as per your business needs.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt got much clarity on question but for updating value based on select here is the example (https://jsfiddle.net/49bt3scn/5/)

reference function

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelector("#Select1");
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
    data[0][2] = x.value
    var node = document.createElement("div");
        node.innerHTML = data[0][1] / data[0][2];
        demo.append(node);
    }
```